# What is the common way to handle successful REST POST operation in UI using React and Redux

Tags: javascript, rest, design-patterns, reactjs, redux

I have a Thread component responsible to render messages of the specific thread and a component to submit a new message. Thread component's state is managed by *Redux*, which provides asynchronous actions like *FETCH_MESSAGES* and *POST_MESSAGE*. Below is the simplified pseudo-code.

```
class Thread {
  messages: [] // This is actually a prop connected to Redux
  render = () => {
    messages.map(messageComponent)
    <SubmitMessageComponent />
  }
}
```

What is the common way to handle successful POST operation of new Message in the UI, when server sends the object back with id? Is it safe to push that object to the array of earlier fetched messages or should I fetch all messages again to ensure consistency? First operation seems efficient but disjointed. I'm considered about handling concurrent REST API operations from different sources properly. Fetching everything all over again would always ensure the consistency of the state, but would be redundant performance wise (Imagine there are near infinite amount of messages)

Is there de facto way to deal with create operation in web application user interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical way to handle this is to reduce the state via a "messages" reducer handling the `POST_MESSAGE` action as you stated in your question, i.e something like this :

```
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
    switch (action.type) {
        [...]
        case POST_MESSAGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                messages: {
                    ...state.messages,
                    [action.id]: { ...action.message }
                }
            }
        [...]
    }
}
```

You didn't explain how and when you're fetching new messages, but if you're using some websocket the messages are pushed from the server to your app.

Maybe an other solution could be to add some timestamp to the `POST_MESSAGE` action, so the server can respond with only the newly appended messages from that time but not sure if it's really RESTfull.

Comment: im fetching the messages using http get when component is mounted. it's no real time messaging but i manually dispatch fetch action when i need fresh data. also, im using reducer combosition, so is it possible to modify that chunk of state handled by fetch reducer in post reducer?

Comment: You're using reducer composition but all your reducers keeps receiving all actions, so it's totally fine (and even somewhat necessary) to respond to the `POST_MESSAGE` action in the fetch reducer. I think you shouldn't have named your reducers like this, because both of them are handling the same slice of the states, i.e : the messages.